# Is telling jokes a good topic for this site?

Tags: discussion

We've recently received a question meant entirely for humor:

[What's your favorite biology joke? [on hold]](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20592/whats-your-favorite-biology-joke)

This post is  a reference point to go back on if these questions should arise in the future.

What are your thoughts on the question? Ie, is it good for attracting new users? Will it degrade the question quality of the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is off-topic. The question is not a useful question as defined in the [Help Center](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - general questions about biological concepts
> - questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions
> - questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

As this site is still in beta, and still is being defined by the community, voting to close questions that aren't a good prototype is a good idea, and I think the community did right to downvote/close it.